# How to open a file in Notepad in a given window size?

Tags: windows-10, window, size

I have a small text file1 used as memo, that I wish to open in a corner of my screen. I know PostIts-like apps but, here, the need is file1.txt with 4 short lines.

I can't find an option in the command line of notepad; I couldn't find relevant info from Bing nor Google. I did not yet ask an "AI", and if possible would like to find an easy solution (no coding). In an old past, there were .ini files with such stuff.

My idea is to copy Notepad.exe as MyNotepadCopy.exe, and open my file with it: it would remember "my" size, while other text file would open normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Notepad, re-position and re-size the window, then close Notepad, the next time you open it, it'll appear as it was when you closed it. The settings are saved in the registry for the current user `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad`